# How to fetch bad-port (6666) in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

In node.js `v18.14.0`
I'm trying to fetch data from port 6666 (url is just a placeholder in this example):

`await fetch("http://placeholder.com:6666/secret-service", {"method": "GET"});`

I receive following error:

```
Error: bad port
    at makeNetworkError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6714:35)
    at mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13496:20)
    at fetching (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13483:7)
    at fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13361:20)
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14150:18)
    at fetch (node:internal/process/pre_execution:237:25)
```

I think this might be connected to the [fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/):

> 2.9. Port blocking
>
> A port is a bad port if it is listed in the first column of the following table.
>
> ...

Unfortunately port 6666 is on the list of the bad ports.

My problem is that I need to fetch data anyway. I cannot simply change the port the service is running on.

How to force nodejs to fetch data from bad port?

Comment: Since your host is localhost, wouldn't it be trivial to just not listen on a bad port? pick any other one that isn't in the table.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it is an example, in fact i am querrying external resource. 
I shall edit my question replacing localhost with my-production-url to avoid this miscommunication

Comment: I suspect something can be done natively using `net.createConnection` but I haven't tested it. And even if it's doable, it isn't an actual answer to the question about fetch, just another workaround.

Comment: Another thing I am thinking is using `http.get` or `https.get`. But you may manually need to handle things like 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue and discovered that Node's global `fetch` implementation is internally provided by the [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici) package.

We were able to fetch from a "bad" port by:

- adding `undici` as a dependency of our package (instead of using the hidden one bundled with Node)
- directly importing its internal `badPorts` constant, and removing the ports that we cared about
- replacing the `fetch` global with the one from the `undici` package

Add this code to `monkeypatch-fetch.js`:

```js
// Get the badPorts list from the original undici module.
const badPorts = require('undici/lib/fetch/constants').badPorts;

// Remove envoy port
const index = badPorts.indexOf('10080');
if (index !== -1) {
  badPorts.splice(index, 1);
}

// Replace global fetch with our monkeypatched fetch
global.fetch = require('undici').fetch;
```

And in your entrypoint, make sure that `monkeypatch-fetch.js` is required before anything else that might want to fetch from the "bad" port.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to find a way to force internal node's fetch api to download from port 6666.
It is possible though to fetch from this port using third-party library [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Library installation: `node install axios`

Code:

```
import axios from "axios";
await axios({method: 'GET', url: "localhost:6666/my-url"})
```

I would still appreciate native solution, but workaround will work in a pinch.